# Center Column without appearing too thin on Mobile in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What is the best way to keep page content centered without appearing too thin when viewed on mobile? This is using a centered single column layout.

When I view the following on a desktop, it achieves the desired look and spacing, but on mobile the content is constrained to too small an area and appears far too narrow.

---

```
<section id="copybox" class="pl-sm-1 pl-md-5 pr-sm-1 pr-md-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-7">
            (Area consisting of multiple div's, paragraphs etc)
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: use `col-11 col-md-7`? or some other col combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `col-7` which is always going to take up 58.333% of the width of it's parent. Use a wider column (ie: `col-10`, `col-11`, `col-12`, etc...) on mobile.

```
<section id="copybox" class="pl-sm-1 pl-md-5 pr-sm-1 pr-md-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-10 border">
            (Area consisting of multiple div's, paragraphs etc)
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ueIUlH19DB

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wider columns as [Zim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zim) suggested. 
Also, make sure to have a viewport meta tag in html page

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```